# PHP - selecting more than one variable in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, select

Forgive me if I find this hard to explain.
Currently the code is working, however all I want to do now, is to execute the same task but with more tasks at once, for example, Task2 inside of the Task1.

I thought this would be possible by using the 'IN' statement inside of the SQL. So by doing this:

```
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM task where task IN ('$FirstTask', $SecondTask');";
```

I hoped that this would then insert the correct data for monday and tuesday am tasks, but when I print $one I get the value of 0 so I don't think that is the right way to go about it.
The only other way I can think of doing this, is by repeating the whole process and slightly changing the variable names to coincide with the day, is there a better way to do this? Hopefully you will understand, if not I can add more information.

EDIT: If I try to use:

```
select * from task where task IN ('$FirstTask', '$SecondTask', '$ThirdTask', '$ForthTask');";
```

This prints the data that I want, however if a value inside of one of them tasks is the same it messes up with the select. 
e.g.

```
mysql> select id,task from task where task IN ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task11', 'Task12');
+-------+------------+
| am_id | am_task    |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | Task1      |
|     2 | Task2      |
|    11 | Task11     |
|    12 | Task12     |
+-------+------------+
```

If I add the same value:

```
mysql> select id,task from task where task IN ('Task1', 'Task2', 'Task11', 'Task4' 'Task2');
+-------+------------+
| am_id | am_task    |
+-------+------------+
|     1 | Task1      |
|     2 | Task2      |
|    11 | Task11     |
+-------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `$tuesday_am_Task` is not `$tuesday_am_task` ...

Comment: another thing you are missing an inverted coma `IN ('$monday_am_task', '$tuesday_am_Task');`

Comment: Must have been syntax when I tried it, sorry, it prints monday's task now. Think I need to add into this now: "UPDATE `timesheet_submission` SET `monday_am_task`='$new' WHERE date between '$date_grab' AND date_add('$date_grab', interval 6 day)"; by entering `monday_am_task`='$new' and `tuesday_am_task`='$new' it doesn't seem to update the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was by using `UNION`, for example:

```
(select id,task from task where id = '12') union (select id,task from task where id='11') union (select id,task from task where id='10');
```

Which then displays:

```
+-------+----------------+
| id | task              |
+-------+----------------+
|    12 | Task12         |
|    11 | Task11         |
|    10 | Task10         |
+-------+----------------+
```